# Some doubts about right ideals of a ring

Tags: ring-theory, notation, ideals

I would like to know whether the following paragraph regarding right ideals and modules is correct. Any comment or help is welcome:

A right ideal of $R$ is just a submodule of the right $R$-module $R_R$ using the operation in $R$. To put it in the conventional symbols: a right ideal $T$ of a ring $(R,+,⋅)$ is a subgroup of $(R,+)$ such that for all $t ∈ T$, $r ∈ R$, we have $t⋅r ∈ T$. 
The quotient $R_R/T_R$ is itself only a right module: it is a ring only if $T$ is a two-sided ideal.

Comment: *A fortiori*, the axioms of ring multiplication allow you to conclude $R$ is a right $R$ module with the ring multiplication as the action. That right ideals are the same thing as right submodules follows directly from the definitions. And finally yes, the quotient being a ring necessitates $T$ being a two-sided ideal. Is there any question left?

Answer (score 1):

Given a ring $R$, right $R$-modules are denoted with $R$ as a right index as in the following: $$M_R$$
this notation recalls you that you can multiply elements of $M_R$ with elements of $R$ on the right i.e. multiplication is a map
$$M_R \times R \longrightarrow M_R\ \ \ (m,r) \mapsto mr$$

Now, the right $R$-module $R_R$ consists of the additive group $(R,+)$ with right multiplication
$$R_R \times R \longrightarrow R_R \ \ \ (a,b) \mapsto ab$$
elements of $R_R$ must be thought as vectors, elements of $R$ must be thought as scalars.

Comment: So should I write RR as R (capital)R (index)??

Comment: Exactly. This is a right $R$-module.

Comment: the left R-module would then be written as R(index size) R (capital letter).......is that correct?

Comment: In the expression: "The quotient RR/TR is itself only a right module: it is a ring only if T is a two-sided ideal. " Should I also apply the same notation to RR? THat is, capital R followed by smaller R?

Comment: Is this notation correct in this context of explanation?: . The quotient R(capital)R(index)/T(capital)R(index) is itself only a right module: it is a ring only if T is a two-sided ideal.

Comment: @JavierArias Yes: this is the correct notation.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was, but it is always nice to know it with absolute certainty.